# How to add a where clause to an EF query which has a grouping

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to find the number of bookings each user has made. This code works great - it does a join onto bookings and groups them and then does a count.

```
var bookingsByUser = from u in _repo.Users()
  join b in _repo.Bookings() on u.UserId equals b.CreatedByUserId
  into g
  select new { UserId = u.UserId, TotalBookings = g.Count() };
```

However, I now want to exclude a certain restaurant, so I try to add a where clause:

```
var bookingsByUser = from u in _repo.Users()
  join b in _repo.Bookings() on u.UserId equals b.CreatedByUserId
  where b.RestaurantId != 21 
  into g
  select new { UserId = u.UserId, TotalBookings = g.Count() };
```

However now I get an error "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause". I can't seem to use "where" on the join table to filter the records before grouping. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Remove: [where b.RestaurantId != 21] and modified: _repo.Bookings().Where(p=>p.RestaurantId !=21)

Comment: Thank you this worked too - however I thought it was unadvisable to mix method and query syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bookingsByUser = from u in _repo.Users()
                     join b in _repo.Bookings() on u.UserId equals b.CreatedByUserId
                     where b.RestaurantId != 21
                     group b by u.UserId into sub
                     select new {
                         UserId = sub.Key,
                         TotalBookings = sub.Count()
                     };
```